# JSTL custom function with an ArrayList<E> return type

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

This may be more of an XML problem than JSTL itself, but I'm not sure.

I'm trying to write a custom JSTL function that returns an ArrayList with a custom defined type.

Here is my `.tld` entry for that function

```
<function>
  <name>timeZonesArray</name>
  <function-class>sessionmanager.JSTLFunctions</function-class>
  <function-signature>java.util.ArrayList<sessionManager.TimeZone> timeZonesArray()     </function-signature>
</function>
```

I have written all the other codes required i.e. the java function itself returning the correct type, but when I tried to run it, server gives this error:
*Unable to initialize TldLocationsCache: XML parsing error on file `/WEB-INF/misc-functions.tld` exactly for that line in `<function-signature>`.

Any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: Did you try using `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of those angular brackets?

Comment: are you added the <taglib> tag in web.xml file?

Comment: @Rohit Jain: I tried it and it worked! Can you please post your comment as an answer? ^_^